# How to catch a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm trying to figure out how to catch a numberformat exception error within my code such that if the user inputs a letter within a string and my program tries to parse it to an int my program won't throw up an error but instead stop and return a Boolean value. I'm also trying to understand that if the try statement works I'd like it to continue to execute the following code.

```
    if (counter == 3) {
        int compare;
        boolean check = true;
        String[] newip = IpAddress.split("\\.");
        if (newip.length == 4) {
            for (int index = 0; index < newip.length; index++) {
                //There should be a try statement here.
                // if the try statement fails then I'd like for it to catch
                // the numberformatexception and evaluate my boolean to 
                //false;
                //but if it passes I'd like for it to continue to execute 
                //the following code.
                    compare = Integer.parseInt(newip[index]);
                if (compare >= 0 & (compare <= 255)) {
                    check = true;
                }
                else{
                    check = false;
                }
            }
            if (check)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else {
            check = false;
            return check;
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the code that might throw an exception, and in the catch block, do what you want in the case of an error (In your case `return false`)

Comment: Please (re)read your Java guide on what a `try` statement is and how it works.

Comment: @Andreas I don't think a try-catch block is needed here imho. As the inputted String must be an Integer, he/she should just check if only digits are present. Another story if the inputted value is formatted, but that is off-topic

Comment: @LppEdd *"should just check if only digits are present"* That's not enough, since `NumberFormatException` can be thrown even if string is all digits, i.e. if string exceeds the range of `int`.

Comment: @Andreas sure. Not a requirement by the question however.

Comment: @LppEdd How do you figure that it is "not a requirement"? OP want that the program *"won't throw up an error"*. That's a requirement. Unless you manually validate that the string is not a number exceeding range of an `int`, the only way to ensure that is to catch the exception. And *that* is exactly the question posed: how to catch a numberformat exception.

Comment: @Andreas "such that if the user inputs a letter within a string". Anyway, I understand what you're saying. Note that catching an exception isn't really the best way to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 2):

Surround that line with try/catch:

```
try {
    compare = Integer.parseInt(newip[index]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    check = false;
}
```

and then:

```
if (check) {
    if (compare >= 0 & (compare <= 255)) {
        check = true;
    } else {
        check = false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of catching NumberFormatException, you can use [NumberUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber-java.lang.String-) from [commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) `3.x` to check if the input is a number.

```
NumberUtils.isNumber(newip[index])
```

However as per the documentation, it would be deprecated in `4.x` and you would need to use [isCreatable](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isCreatable-java.lang.String-)

```
NumberUtils.isCreatable(newip[index])
```